# How can I test Web and MS Office in a single integration test?

Tags: web-applications, ms-office, integration-testing, openoffice.org

I've seen lots of posts on Selenium for web integration testing, but not for web and office documents (MS Office or OpenOffice).

I would like to create an integration test to test opening a document over WebDAV and saving the document to a given location (can be Windows or Linux path).

Does anyone know of a framework that would support the following steps in a single integration test?

1. Send a HTTP request to a server, say `http://myserver/mypath`.
2. Simulate a URL click on a link like `http://myserver/mypath/mydoc.doc`.
3. When mydoc.doc opens on the client (in MS Office or OpenOffice) enter some text and save it to  a given location.
4. Close mydoc.doc (closing whatever application handles it, i.e. Word or OpenOffice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, looks like http://sikuli.org will do the trick, have yet to test it though